# Javascript to MySQL Datetime format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a Javascript file that populates 2 grids with data from 2 different tables in MySql.  In the one grid, the format of the date looks like this: **"1970-01-01T04:15:00.000+0000"**.  In the other, it looks like this: **"1663286400000"**.  The fields in the two tables are the same; both are DATETIME.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: It looks like you are using different kind of formats, while printing the dates on JavaScript side. Take a look if the date format is different.